# PHP function in function (no OOP) works weird

Tags: php, function

I'm not in OOP and I would like understand why in the procedural mode I can declare a function nestled in a function without errors, but I can call the nestled function from the "main" and cannot call from the primary function?

Example 1: calling b() in a() gives Fatal error / Why a() doesn't views b() ?

```
<?php
function a(){
  // do something
  b(); //Fatal error: Call to undefined function b()

  function b(){
    // do something
  }
}

a();
```

Example 2: calling b() from the main gives Fatal error (this is logic)

```
<?php
function a(){
  //  do something

  function b(){
    // do something
  }
} 

b(); // Fatal error: Call to undefined function b()
```

Example 3: calling a() and then calling b() from the main doesn't give error

```
<?php
function a(){
    //  do something

    function b(){
        // do something
    }

}

a();
b();
```

Comment: probably because your syntax is incorrect

Comment: Just follow the flow of the script, the function is *still* undefined when you try to call it in #1 and #2. By the way, this is bound to give you trouble later on as you can only call `a()` once during the whole execution of your script.

Comment: Nesting functions in PHP is rarely what you want to do - it means that `b()` is only declared once you first call `a()`, and will raise an error about redeclaring an existing function if you ever call `a()` again. Both functions will be declared in global scope, which isn't necessarily obvious.

Comment: @iainn surely, but suppose I need to use the function b() only in the function a() ... probably it shall be better use a LAMBDA function I suppose

Comment: @ViDiVe Yes, you should absolutely use a locally scoped anonymous function in that case. Having the functions nested as you have will cause issues with both scope and re-usability.

Comment: Thanks @iainn, I've understood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is a procedural programming language. It will do each line, in order. The reason you can't call `b()` from within `a()` is because, at that point, `b()` has not been declared. What you want to do is declare your function *before* calling it:

```
<?php
function a(){
  // do something

  function b(){
    // do something
  }
  b(); 

}

a();
```

This is still bad practice though. Break `b()` out of `a()` :

```
<?php
function a(){
  // do something

  b();

}
function b(){
  // do something
}

a();
```

This will allow you to call `a()` and `b()` at any time.

Comment: Thanks, now I've understood!